# How to get collection name on express.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 collections

```
appoinments
invoice
```

in my post method, before saving data, I check that data already exists, but I want only the `appoinments` collection.
I want to save `invoice` colection  normally. How can I do this. I already tried with if statement but it didn't work.

```
app.post('/collections/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.body[0])
   if('/collections/:collectionName' == '/collections/appoinments'){
      req.collection.findOne({hour_responce:req.body[0].hour_responce}, function(e, result){
          if(result){
            console.log(result); console.log(e)
            res.send(500,{error:"You Already have a Task on this Time Period"})
          }
          else{
            req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
            if (e) return next(e)
            res.send(results)

             })
          }
      })
  }
  else{
     req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
            if (e) return next(e)
            res.send(results)
        })
  }

})
```

Comment: `if('/collections/:collectionName' == '/collections/appoinments')` will never match. Try `if(req.params.collectionName == 'appointments')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot add a comment, so I try to give some advices by adding an answer

First :

appointments or appoinments? Be careful with spelling

Second :

Ben Fortune is right. may be use :

if(req.params.collectionName == 'appoinments')

Third :

It seems that you are using mongodb ( I see some keywords like collection, findOne). The right way to query a collection with native mongdb node driveris is like:
    db.collection.findOne(query,callback);

Honestly, I didn't understand the "req.collection.findOne"

Good luck